# How to execute a multiline command using ssh on a remote Linux machine?

Tags: powershell, ssh, stdin, multiline

My local machine has Windows OS. My remote machine has Linux OS. I'm trying to run some bash commands on the remote machine from my local machine (with the use of `ssh`). In the `powershell` script below I'm feeding a `multiline` comment to `stdin` input of ssh client. The code does not work and gives me an error. The problem is that each line passed to bash has `\r` (carriage return symbol) appended to it and bash interprets it as a part of a command. What are my options here?

**Powershell script**

```
ssh -tt "$Username@$Host" @"
    cd /home/someuser/project
    cd ~
"@
```

**Bash error**

```
bash: line 0: cd: $'/home/someuser/project\r': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Since you are asking about tunning bash, why put this on a PowerShell Q&A? Are you saying you want to run your bash command in a PS remoting script? There are many SO Q&A's the cover running bash from PowerShell. Just use the SO search box above. As well as many bash via PowerShell all over the web. What did you search for? What did you try? Specifically, when trying to do this via PowerShell. Just save your command as a .sh and run it from PowerShell. As long as you have your ENVIR variables properly set.

Comment: @postanote, hey! I should have been more clear in my question. Fixed the description. Sorry.

Comment: It works on my W10 computer with PS 5.1 and ssh installed through WSL (if I remember well). Remote tested servers are RHEL with bash also. 
According to your analysis, did you simply tried to replace your string ? `@"..."@ -replace "\`r\`n", "\`n"` for instance (I guess it won't convert the last line however)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you execute `ssh` from Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core on Windows as it is using CRLF for line breaks. `bash` doesn't like CRLF. So, concatenate your commands with line delimiters and pass it to `ssh` in one line:

```
ssh -tt "$Username@$Host" "cd /home/someuser/project; cd ~"
```

If it is a larger script, you can maintain it in a file an convert it automatically to a (not really) "one-liner":

```
$myBashScript = (Get-Content 'my-bash-script.txt') -join ';'
ssh -tt "$Username@$Host" $myBashScript
```

Comment: I fear that the second approach would cause issues when a script has `if else` statements.

Comment: @manidos Yes, it won't work for every complexity.

Comment: I did not test it, but `Start-Process ssh -ArgumentList "-tt $Username@$Host" -RedirectStandardInput my-bash-script.txt` might also be worth a look.